# Как скачивать библиотеки в пайчарме?

Tags: pycharm

Не могу понять как в пайчарм скачивать библиотеки и вообще чтолибо устанавливать, может быть я не там пишу? Например, мне нужна библиотека !pip aiogram , он мне пишет ошибка синтаксиса, и так на все, я писала и в само файле майн.пай и в косоли, где писать то?)) Подскажите начинающему, пожалуйста

Comment: не `!pip aiogram`, а `pip install aiogram`. Плюс у вас должен быть предварительно установлен питон и, желательно, создано и активировано виртуальное окружение

Answer (score 0):

Pip указывается без!. И команда для установки aiogram выглядит так "pip install aiogram". Вводить её надо в терминал.

Answer (score 0):

В PyCharm пакеты также можно устанавливать через графический интерфейс:

- Нажимаете на значок пакетов (в нижнем левом углу);
- введите название пакета в полу ввода;
- Нажмите `Install package`.

Вот скрин для понимания (для примера библиотека `numpy`):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]